# Publishing Word Add-In for use by customers

Tags: office-store

We are developing a Word Web Add-In that will be used exclusively by our customers rather than the general public.  Customers will need to log into the Add-In in order to use it with credentials we supply.  My question is, is this Add-In ok to be distributed via the Office Store?  Will it fall foul of the validation process if its functionality is not publicly available ?  Obviously, we can supply credentials to the verification team at Microsoft in order to get the app published.

If this is a problem, how do ISVs distribute Web Add-Ins to customers external to their organisation (i.e. Without Sharepoint or Office Admin Centre)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This model is supported via the Office Store - [this](https://dev.office.com/blogs/office-store-validation-policy-changes-to-support-apps-and-add-ins-that-target-larger-organizations-and-enterprises) blog post on add-ins which target organizations and enterprises rather than consumers may be of interest to you.

Please ensure that your add-in description clearly states the need for an additional account, as well as supplying test credentials for the validation team to use.